# AWS Boto3 list only specific filetype to avoid pagination

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to list all my csv files in an s3 bucket for the preparation of another process. However, by using the `list_objects_V2` function of the boto3 library a maximum of 1.000 objects is returned. My bucket has 10.000 jpg images and 500 csv files.

I figured out that I could use pagination by passing the next token. However, I thought their must be some way to restrict the response to only csv files so I would not exceed the 1.000 max items limit. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: *"However, I thought their must be some way to restrict the response to only csv files"* - nope. Use pagination or put the csv files into a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at this link https://alexwlchan.net/2017/07/listing-s3-keys/

Specifically the function get_matching_s3_keys, because it filters on prefix, suffix and and applies pagenation. Granted that the suffix filter is only applied after the data is retrieved from the API - but it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `resource` method as follows:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
objs = s3.Bucket('example_bucket').objects.filter(Prefix='prefix')
csvs = []

for obj in objs:
    if obj.key.endswith('.csv'): csvs.append(obj.key)
    
print(csvs)
```

which will show all the resources without pagination but it take much time when you have a lot of objects in the bucket with the same prefix.